# Android market says I must specify a min sdk version

Tags: android, sdk, version, google-play

I've been trying to publish an app on the android market and I keep getting this error "Market requires the minSdkVersion to be set to a positive 32-bit integer in AndroidManifest.xml" I looked at all the other posts and followed the instructions adding the android:minSdkVersion and android:targetSdkVersion and it is still giving me the same error when I try to upload the new .apk file. Here is my manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.seeshi.coffee"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">


<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
             android:theme="@style/CoffeeStyle" 
             android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">
<uses-sdk    android:minSdkVersion="4" 
             android:targetSdkVersion="4" />
<supports-screens
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:smallScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />



    <activity android:name=".Start"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Browse" />

    <activity android:name=".CoffeeTypes" />

</application>
```

Comment: It looks good to me. The only thing I can think of is maybe their checker parser ins't very good. Try putting the uses-sdk stuff all on one line with just one space between each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving the uses-sdk tag outside of the the application tags.

Answer (score 2):

The uses-sdk tag  should be outside of the application tags.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are actually trying to upload the new APK.  I suggest you delete the old one so you cannot get mixed up.

Also, try putting the `sdk` details above the `application` tag.